# reading DNS packets in Python

Tags: python, sockets, character-encoding, dns, udp

I'm playing around with Python sockets, and decided to see if I could implement a very basic name server (i.e. a lookup table for a domain name to an IP address). So I've set up my server so far to just dump the received data.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
host = ''
port = 53
size = 512
s.bind((host, port))
while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(size)
    print repr(data)
```

When I run the above code and point my DNS to 127.0.0.1 I get something akin to the following:

```
'Y\x04\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03www\x06google\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01'
'J\xaa\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03www\x06google\x03com\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x01'
'Y\x04\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03www\x06google\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01'
```

I'm assuming that it is something to do with the DNS question packet structure, but I'm not to sure.

A) Are the above escape characters? A specific text encoding? Or simply just bytes?

B) How can I interpret the data and work with it?

EDIT: Changing the socket to take raw instead of datagrams results in the following:

```
'E\x00$\x00\xe4\x96\x00\x00@\x01\x00\x00\x7f\x00\x00\x01\x7f\x00\x00\x01\x03\x03X\xb6\x00\x00\x00\x00E\x00V\x00m\x82\x00\x00\xff\x11\x00\x00\x7f\x00\x00\x01\x7f\x00\x00\x01\xf3\xe1\x005\x00B\x00\x00'
```

Comment: if you just need the domain name over the ip.. you can do `socket.getfqdn("173.194.37.144")` also `socket.getfqdn("www.google.com")`

Comment: Thanks, I'm curious about implementing my own simple solution though, definitely keep that one in mind though!

Comment: try scapy http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/, it will decode for you

Comment: Is there a way to grab that data as an array of bytes then?

Comment: `map(ord, list(data))` in python2.x and just `list(data)` in python3.x, but I strongly recommend decoding it with the help of the `struct` module instead.

Answer (score 7):

You could start with something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pprint
import socket
import struct


def decode_labels(message, offset):
    labels = []

    while True:
        length, = struct.unpack_from("!B", message, offset)

        if (length & 0xC0) == 0xC0:
            pointer, = struct.unpack_from("!H", message, offset)
            offset += 2

            return labels + decode_labels(message, pointer & 0x3FFF), offset

        if (length & 0xC0) != 0x00:
            raise StandardError("unknown label encoding")

        offset += 1

        if length == 0:
            return labels, offset

        labels.append(*struct.unpack_from("!%ds" % length, message, offset))
        offset += length


DNS_QUERY_SECTION_FORMAT = struct.Struct("!2H")

def decode_question_section(message, offset, qdcount):
    questions = []

    for _ in range(qdcount):
        qname, offset = decode_labels(message, offset)

        qtype, qclass = DNS_QUERY_SECTION_FORMAT.unpack_from(message, offset)
        offset += DNS_QUERY_SECTION_FORMAT.size

        question = {"domain_name": qname,
                    "query_type": qtype,
                    "query_class": qclass}

        questions.append(question)

    return questions, offset


DNS_QUERY_MESSAGE_HEADER = struct.Struct("!6H")

def decode_dns_message(message):

    id, misc, qdcount, ancount, nscount, arcount = DNS_QUERY_MESSAGE_HEADER.unpack_from(message)

    qr = (misc & 0x8000) != 0
    opcode = (misc & 0x7800) >> 11
    aa = (misc & 0x0400) != 0
    tc = (misc & 0x200) != 0
    rd = (misc & 0x100) != 0
    ra = (misc & 0x80) != 0
    z = (misc & 0x70) >> 4
    rcode = misc & 0xF

    offset = DNS_QUERY_MESSAGE_HEADER.size
    questions, offset = decode_question_section(message, offset, qdcount)

    result = {"id": id,
              "is_response": qr,
              "opcode": opcode,
              "is_authoritative": aa,
              "is_truncated": tc,
              "recursion_desired": rd,
              "recursion_available": ra,
              "reserved": z,
              "response_code": rcode,
              "question_count": qdcount,
              "answer_count": ancount,
              "authority_count": nscount,
              "additional_count": arcount,
              "questions": questions}

    return result


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
host = ''
port = 53
size = 512
s.bind((host, port))
while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(size)
    pprint.pprint(decode_dns_message(data))
```

And then fill in the decoding functions for the remaining records.

Comment: The complete DNS record can be larger than 512.  Also, receive might not receive the whole buffer in go even if it is big enough.

Comment: You are correct. I was just going off of OP's code and giving them something to start with. But yeah, you need to be aware of how to handle the packets properly (and by extension the whole protocol) if you're going to put an own implementation into production.

Comment: Upon a little further investigation, I currently think I am wrong, although the python docs are not clear on this.  I now think the `512` above is the minimum bytes to be read before `recv` will return.  It doesn't define the maximum.  (Python recv automatically generates the necessary buffer, however big).  In addition, I'm under the impression that for UDP/DNS, a single DNS transaction always fits in a single UDP frame, and a UDP is always transmitted atomically (or fails).  So your code is perfect, AFAIK.  My own DNS testing shows recv(1024) getting buffers size 4096.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example to send and receive `dns` packets using socket and [dnslib](https://pypi.org/project/dnslib/):

```
import socket
from dnslib import DNSRecord

forward_addr = ("8.8.8.8", 53) # dns and port
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
qname = "duckgo.com" # query 
q = DNSRecord.question(qname)
client.sendto(bytes(q.pack()), forward_addr)
data, _ = client.recvfrom(1024)
d = DNSRecord.parse(data)
print("r", str(d.rr[0].rdata)) # prints the A record of duckgo.com
```