# python dns sniffer without scapy module

Tags: python, dns, unpack, sniffer

I'm going to make my own python DNS sniffer without scapy module, but i have no idea how to unpack it!!

In this case i want to know when i send nslookup google.com command, The sniffer shows me: google.com

So how can i to know what is Queries field value.

My half code:

```
import socket

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PROT = 53

sk = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sk.bind(("0.0.0.0", PROT))

data, addr = sk.recvfrom(512)
print "DNS Query from:", addr, "\n", repr(data)
```

My output:

```
DNS Query from: ('127.0.0.1', 49135) 
'\xd2N\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08google\x02com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01'
```

Thank you.

Comment: It’s not that easy. You have to look at the RFC https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt and understand how a DNS packet is built. Then, you’ll have to check the bytes you are returning for each field and check the different cases (options, padding, compression....). You’ll also have to implement a way of decompressing the packet (good luck on that :/). This is why scapy is easier

Comment: Yes it's easy to use scapy but you don't know really what to do with dns header

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16981944/5459467 has the answer you seek