# How to parse DNS Question field with python raw sockets?

Tags: python, dns, raw-sockets

I'm trying to parse question field in a DNS packet where I can read domain and DNS response from a DNS server. I can extract a DNS header, but I'm having trouble to parse the question field because the size of the data is unknown.

I follow this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977588/reading-dns-packets-in-python/16981944#16981944), but the part of extracting the question field is not working.
[image]

What I need is someone to show me the way to do it properly.

I have this code where everything is right...

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from socket import *
import struct
import binascii

def ethernet_frame(raw_data):
    mac_dest, mac_src, protocol = struct.unpack('! 6s 6s H', 
    raw_data[:14])
    return byte_to_hex_mac(mac_dest), byte_to_hex_mac(mac_src), 
            htons(protocol), raw_data[14:]


def byte_to_hex_mac(mac_bytes):
    addr = binascii.hexlify(mac_bytes).decode("ascii")
    return ":".join([addr[i:i+2] for i in range(0,12,2)])


def data_packet_udp(data):
    tuple_data_udp = struct.unpack('! H H H H', data[:8])
    port_src = tuple_data_udp[0]
    port_dest = tuple_data_udp[1]
    udp_len = tuple_data_udp[2]
    udp_checksum = tuple_data_udp[3]
    return port_src, port_dest, udp_len, udp_checksum, data[8:]


def data_packet_ipv4(data):
    tuple_data_ipv4 = struct.unpack("!BBHHHBBH4s4s", data[:20])
    version = tuple_data_ipv4[0]
    header_len = version >> 4
    type_service = tuple_data_ipv4[1]
    length_total = tuple_data_ipv4[2]
    identification = tuple_data_ipv4[3]
    offset_fragment = tuple_data_ipv4[4]
    ttl = tuple_data_ipv4[5]
    protocols = tuple_data_ipv4[6]
    checksum_header = tuple_data_ipv4[7]
    ip_src = inet_ntoa(tuple_data_ipv4[8])
    ip_dest = inet_ntoa(tuple_data_ipv4[9])
    length_header_bytes = (version & 15) * 4 
    return version, header_len, type_service, + \
          length_total, identification, offset_fragment, + \
          ttl, protocols, checksum_header, ip_src, ip_dest, 
             data[length_header_bytes:] 


def data_packet_dns(data):
    tuple_data_dns = struct.unpack('!HHHHHH', data[:12])
    identification = tuple_data_dns[0]
    flags = tuple_data_dns[1] 
    number_queries = tuple_data_dns[2]
    number_response = tuple_data_dns[3]
    number_authority = tuple_data_dns[4]
    number_additional = tuple_data_dns[5]
    qr = (flags & 32768) != 0
    opcode = (flags & 30720 ) >> 11
    aa = (flags & 1024) != 0
    tc = (flags & 512) != 0
    rd = (flags & 256) != 0
    ra = (flags & 128) != 0
    z = (flags & 112) >> 4
    rcode = flags & 15
    return identification, flags, number_queries, number_response, + \
          number_authority, number_additional, qr, opcode, aa, tc, + \
          rd, ra, z, rcode

sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, ntohs(0x0003))    

while True:
    raw_dados, addr = sock.recvfrom(65536)
    mac_dest, mac_src, protocol, payload = ethernet_frame(raw_dados)
    if protocol == 8:
         ( version, header_len, type_service,
        length_total, identification, offset_fragment,
        ttl, protocols, checksum_header,
        ip_src, ip_dest, data ) = data_packet_ipv4(payload)
        if protocols == 17:
             port_src, port_dest, udp_len, udp_checksum, data = 
              data_packet_udp(data)
            print("--------- HEADER UDP ----------")
            print("Port Source : {}".format(port_src))
            print("Port Dest : {}".format(port_dest))
            print("UDP Length : {}".format(udp_len))
            print("UDP Checksum : {}\n".format(udp_checksum))
            if  port_src == 53 or port_dest == 53:
                  (identification, flags, number_queries, \
                   number_response,number_authority,number_additional, \
                   qr, opcode, aa, tc, rd, ra, z, rcode) = data_packet_dns(data)
             print("\t--------- HEADER DNS ----------")
             print("\tidentification : {}".format(identification))
             print("\tFlags : {}".format(flags))
             print("\tnumber_queries : {}".format(number_queries))
             print("\tnumber_response : {}".format(number_response))
             print("\tnumber_authority : {}".format(number_authority))
             print("\tnumber_additional : {}".format(number_additional))
             print("\tQr : {}".format(qr))
             print("\tOpcode : {}".format(opcode))
             print("\tAA : {}".format(aa))
             print("\tTC : {}".format(tc))
             print("\tRD : {}".format(rd))
             print("\tRA : {}".format(ra))
             print("\tZ : {}".format(z))
             print("\tRCODE : {}".format(rcode))
```

Comment: Studying the dnspython library that parses and builds DNS packets may help you.

Comment: "the size of the data is unknown." not right, the size is known. Read RFC1035 for proper specifications of DNS messages and section "4.1.2. Question section format" specifically that starts with: "a domain name represented as a sequence of labels, where
                each label consists of a length octet followed by that
                number of octets.  The domain name terminates with the
                zero length octet for the null label of the root. " This shows "DNS name compression". Each name has a size prepended first.